# Print a range of characters as a list

Tags: java

So my method is supposed to take to character parameters as the first and last characters in a range and print every letter and its numerical encoding in the range. For example e and j as parameters would print out e f g h i j (except with the nnumerical encoding) 
The code I used doesnt compile. What am I doing wrong

```
public void listCharacterCodes(char a, char b){
    int j = (int) b;
    for(int i =(int) a, i<j,i++){
        println("'" + a + "': " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: What's the compile error you're getting?

Comment: there is not a  println(string); function in Java. System.out.println() exist though

Comment: @Alboz - They may have statically imported `println(String line)`, given how little we've got to go on, but that's a decent guess as to what the problem could well be.

Comment: @Edd looking at the quality of the code I would be surprised if he had done so :p

Comment: Sorry I didnt mention Im using bluej so println(string) and casting chars as ints works. Th error is '; espected'

Comment: @Alboz Seems that's what BlueJ does behind the scenes, and so she was without realising! ;-)

Comment: Now you don't need any answer. your code in question is now work.

Comment: @Edd lol I read it.. :)

Comment: I've put back the broken code into the question so that the question and conversation makes sense.

Comment: Extre info- the code doesnt change the char a it just prints out the same letter each time. It needs to print out the next letter with the corresponding value.

Answer (score 2):

do like this:

```
public static void listCharacterCodes(char a, char b){           
        for(int i =a; i<b;i++){
            System.out.println((char)i +"--"+ i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: remove the useless casts and I'll +1 you .

Comment: that is required other wise it will print `int` value

Comment: not the one in the System.out.println but these ones: int j = (int) b; for(int i =(int)a; i<j;i++)

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void listCharacterCodes(char a, char b){
    int j = (int) b;
    for(int i =(int) a; i<j;i++){
      System.out.println("'" + (char)i + "': " + i);
    }
  }
```

Comment: this will print only `a` check it out.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void listCharacterCodes(char a, char b){
    int j = (int) b;
    int x = (int) a;
    for(int i=x; i<j ; i++) {
        System.out.println("'" + a + "': " + i);
    }
}
```

*This* compiles OK for me - this is not intented to solve your logic - as others did

Comment: you also having same problem. it will print alway 'a' and int value of i